# Cannot join Windows 10 to Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-domain, connector

I have a Windows 10 machine and a Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials machine. 
The Windows Server machine has all latest updates. 
On the Windows 10 machine I installed Client Connector application.

- I can ping the server by name or IP
- I can access the server through Explorer
  using `\\servername` and I'm seeing the shared folders
- Both PCs are  connected to the same Wi-Fi
- Firewall is "ON" on server.

In Client Connector, if I enter wrong user information/password, I get an error immediately, but when I enter a valid credential, after a minute I get the below message:

> The server is not available. Try connecting this computer again.

How can I fix this?

[image: Error in Computer Connector]

Comment: Hard to guess… *1.* Synchronize the date and time on the client computer with those on the server. *2.* Install the Certification Authority Role on the Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials server. *3.* Give your server a static IP address, and set the client DNS to be the server's static IP only (or at least primary). *4.* Move your question to https://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a good document on setting up a new domain controller. I followed the document and was able to join my Windows 10 to domain.

[Building Your First Domain Controller on 2012 R2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22622.building-your-first-domain-controller-on-2012-r2.aspx)

Hope this help other people.